# TGrid значение ячейки

Tags: c++builder, преобразование, grid

Добрый день. Вопрос для кого-то покажется простым, но не могу найти свойство ячейки чтобы получить значение текста в ней. *RAd 10 Siettle C++Builder*.

Необходима таблица, поэтому использую `TGrid`, Значение ячейки содержиться в переменной типа `TValue`, Добраться до нее можно `Form1->Grid1->Colunms[1]->Controls->Items[1]`. Выдает значение типа `TValue`, но если попробовать перевести методом `->ToString()` ты выдает ошибку что в `RTTI:TValue` нет такого метода, если я правильно понял. пробовал через `dynamic_cast`, но тоже не полчается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все оказалось очень просто, именно в версии 10 функции `OnSetValue` значение `Value` стало константным, и поэтому теперь функция тоже немного изменилась.

```
const_cast<TValue*>(&Value)->ToString();
```

А добраться до ячейки можно `Form1->Grid1->Columns[Col]->Controls->Items[Row]` значение будет опять таки `TValue`